# Show two divs side-by-side

Tags: html, css

Consider this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/nashabhu/WbJvP/. I want to show the following `div`s
next to each other.

```
<!--Sidebar--->
    <div class="schoolnav" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 12px;">
        <ul>
            <li>General Information</li>
            <li>Features</li>
            <li>School Images</li>
            <li>Contact Information</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   <!-- End Sidebar -->
    <!-- Container -->
    <div id="container">
      </div>
```

I have it as in the following image right now:

[image]

I want to show the `General Information` in the same row as the `Add School`. How can I do that?

**Edit :**

I just want to get Add New School Block in the same line as the General Information Text is. How can I do that? Answer by Daniel Imms works but it takes the `schoolnav` in the `container`. So the sidebar comes in the ontent rather than on the left side.

Comment: "display:inline-block;" So it wont get new line by default. And float it as required

Comment: @madhairsilence To whom should I apply this rule?To the `schoolnavdiv` or `container` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to do this, we will take `.schoolnav` out of the flow of the page using `position:absolute;` and then give `#main` a `margin-left` equal to the `width` of `.schoolnav`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxLVN/)

[image]

**CSS**

```
#shell {
    position:relative;
}
.schoolnav {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
}    
#main {
    width:788px;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

I moved `.schoolnav` into `#shell`

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="shell">
        <!--Sidebar--->
        <div class="schoolnav" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 12px;">
        ...
```

#### Alternative method

The other usual method to do this sort of thing is to use `float:left;` on both items and set their width's to percentages so they will up the page. The problem with this method though is that you need an additional `div` at the end to clear the floats (or a pseudo-element clearfix).

Comment: No, you have moved all to the right side.I just want to get Add New School block inline with General Information keeping general information at its place as in image included in my question..

Answer (score 0):

Apply `float:left` to both of the `div` tags and set the `width` of each so the total is `100%`

E.g.

```
.schoolnav {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
}

#container {
  float:left;
  width:80%;
}
```

Comment: This is ok but the below containers will mess up and also the OP is applying `margins` and `paddings` you should take care of them too.

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of the following...

Using floats:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container div {
    float: left;
}
```

Using inline-block:

```
.container div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.schoolNav{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#container{
     margin-left:150px;  /* increase this value if you want to */
     /* remove padding: 20px 0  */
}
```

Comment: @BhushanFirake Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WbJvP/3/). I hope this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Add following CSS

```
.schoolnav { float:left }
#container {
     margin-left:165px;
     padding:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: no need of `!important` here. just tell the OP to remove the applied padding.

Comment: @BhushanFirake - you specified **#container { padding:20px 0;}** in JsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

1- Add these lines to your CSS:

```
.schoolnav {display: inline-block;}
#container { padding:20px 0;display: inline-block;}
```

2- In your HTML, rename or remove the **second** `div` that has the class `shell`. It takes all the available width and won't fit in one line with the .schoolnav DIV. The CSS defines a 988px width for it and it is used in the HEADER part for the first time, for here use another class with a proper width. This one:

```
.
.
.
<div id="container">
 <div class="shell"> <!-- rename the class and use another width for it in your CSS -->
.
.
.
```

Your problem should be solved.

Comment: Rename the class of the second DIV with the class "shell" to something else. **It takes all the available width and won't fit in one line with the .schoolnav DIV.**

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in the css of your jsfiddle and found it working as you expect:

```
.schoolnav{float:left; margin-right:20px;}
#container { padding:0; overflow:hidden;}
```

See if works for you.

Answer (score -2):

try :

```
<div></div> &nbsp; <div></div>
```